# resize a window in Xul

Tags: resize, window, xul

Can anyone tell me that how can i resize a window in XUL.I tried resizable but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

To make the window manually resizable, you use what you tried - 'resizable'

```
var myWin = window.openDialog('chrome://myapp/content/mywindow.xul','mywindow','centerscreen,chrome,resizable,dialog=no',{});
```

To resize it programmatically, try the functions [ResizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.resizeTo) or [ResizeBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.resizeBy)

Answer (score 0):

[resizeBy ( width, height )](http://xul-app.hp.infoseek.co.jp/xultu-janit/elemref/ref_XULWindow.html)

Comment: Or resizeTo (http://xul-app.hp.infoseek.co.jp/xultu-janit/elemref/ref_XULWindow.html#prop_resizeTo)